# How to stream exactly what is playing on web with Android

Tags: java, android, live-streaming

I'm stuck on something. I want an application which play the mp3 audio from a URL. I so far build an application which take that web ( URL ), And start playing song from the start and keeps on playing till the end. But I want something Different.

What I want is an app play what is playing right now on a url. Means if the song is at 1:30 min (Playing since last 1:30 min). The application will start it from that time and play it after 1:30.

Here is my Java code. The targeted api is 19. Real time streaming is what I am looking for.

```
    import java.io.IOException;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.app.ActionBar;
    import android.app.Fragment;
    import android.media.AudioManager;
    import android.media.MediaPlayer;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuItem;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.os.Build;

    public class MainActivity extends Activity {
final String song_url[]= {
        "http://soundxx.mp3pk.com/indian/devdas/2%28mp3pk.com%29.mp3"
};

private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer ;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
Button  playb = (Button) findViewById(R.id.playb) ;
Button  stopb = (Button) findViewById(R.id.stopb);
TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);


    mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

    playb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try {
                mediaPlayer.setDataSource(song_url[0]);
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (SecurityException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                mediaPlayer.prepare();
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } // might take long! (for buffering, etc)
            mediaPlayer.start();


        }
    });
    stopb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        mediaPlayer.stop();

        }
    });

}





    }
```

Comment: A reference code or an application tutorial would be great help.

Comment: You can go through http://typicaljava.blogspot.in/2013/03/streaming-media-player-with-song-url.html ,http://www.javatpoint.com/playing-audio-in-android-example, http://android.programmerguru.com/android-mediaplayer-example-play-from-internet/,http://androidtrainningcenter.blogspot.in/2012/09/media-player-example-in-android-with.html, http://davanum.wordpress.com/2007/12/29/android-videomusic-player-sample-from-local-disk-as-well-as-remote-urls/

Comment: Thank you man for giving me starting point.

Comment: They won't help much. I read them all. Way too different from what I want.